# MudCarousel - slide to next/prev and then silently replace the list

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am trying to use `<MudCarousel>` to provide a tinder like experience. To do this I crated a  `MudCarousel.ItemsSource` that is a `List<MyItems>` where the list content is originally: [Item1, Item0, Item1] and set `SelectedIndex=1'.

Then when they swipe either direction, they go from Item0 to Item1. I then rebuild the list with [Item2, Item1, Item2] and call `MudCarousel.MoveTo(1);`

This all works fine. But visually I can't get it to slide to the new item right. Sometimes it does, sometimes it just jumps. And then when I update the ItemsSource, sometimes the content re-renders.

So my question is, in the `MudCarousel.SelectedIndexChanged` method, how do I handle this so:

1. On a swipe/click left/right, it has the previous/next item come sliding into the page?
2. When I update the ItemsSource content and call MoveTo(1), it realizes that is what is showing and thereby does no additional render?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to just play around with delays.

You need a minimum of 1 millisecond `await Task.Delay(1)` after the selectedIndex is changed, however for the carousel UX, I find that 100-200 works best.

```html
<MudCarousel SelectedIndex="selectedIndex" SelectedIndexChanged="HandleIndexChanged">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <!--  -->
    </ItemTemplate>
</MudCarousel>
```

```cs
async Task HandleIndexChanged(int newIndex)
{
    selectedIndex = newIndex;
    await Task.Delay(200);
    if (newIndex != 1)
    {
        await ReBuildItems();
    }
    _carousel.MoveTo(1);
}
```

[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GEGHktaseSIgKFkx)